# Else vs Else If

Tags: javascript

Assuming the following script in question:

```
function range(start, end, step){
  var theRange = [];
  var i = start;
  if(step === undefined){
    if(start < end)
      step = 1;
    else if(start > end)
      step = -1;
  }

  if(step < 0){
     for(;i >= end;i += step){
       theRange.push(i);
     }
  }else{ // just say Else?
    for(;i <= end;i += step){
      theRange.push(i);
    }
  }
  return theRange;
}

function sum(theRange){
  var theSum = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < theRange.length; i++){
    theSum += theRange[i];
  }
  return theSum;
}

console.log(range(5,2));
```

The part where we try to figure out if step is less than 0 or not - would it be better to use Else for when the step is not less than 0, or would it be better to explicitly state the other option with Else if(step > 0)?

So, basically what I'm asking would this code be better in any way(compile/execution time wise, readability, security, or etc.)?:

```
function range(start, end, step){
  var theRange = [];
  var i = start;
  if(step === undefined){
    if(start < end)
      step = 1;
    else if(start > end)
      step = -1;
  }

  if(step < 0){
     for(;i >= end;i += step){
       theRange.push(i);
     }
  }else if(step > 0){ // explicitly state the other possible condition
    for(;i <= end;i += step){
      theRange.push(i);
    }
  }
  return theRange;
}

function sum(theRange){
  var theSum = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < theRange.length; i++){
    theSum += theRange[i];
  }
  return theSum;
}

console.log(range(5,2));
```

Comment: your conditions are not equal when step = 0

Comment: "would it be better to use Else for when the step is not less than 0, or would it be better to explicitly state the other option with Else if" better for what? perf? readability? maintainability?   Also, consider that `step` **is** `0`. having the `else if` would miss that condition

Comment: in this case it should not make much of a difference. But for a more general answer: it is typically a good idea to cover all possible cases (so, have an ´else´ block at the end, and be it only to alert that you missed some possibility. like the case where ´start=end´ :-)

Comment: what do you want to do when `step == end` ? the `else` only variant will handle it, the `else if` one will not.

Comment: @atmd
You're both right and a bit incorrect. But mostly right. If `step` is 0 the function shouldn't do anything, and that what it just does when I pass 0 for `step`. As for "better for what?" - that was my entire point of the question: would it be better at all for anything? Perf? Readability? Maintability? Etc?

Comment: There's no point in adding an `if("all other cases")`  after an else. No point aside from personal preference, which is why I'm close-voting this as _"Opinion-based"_.

Comment: As for the "soft" qualities of readability etc: usually the *fewer* things to consider the better. One condition and an `else` is easy to understand. Two chained conditions can be harder to understand and it's easy to overlook the missing cases (e.g. 0).

Answer (score 3):

There's a logical difference. `if (foo < 0) .. else ..` matches all possible cases. `if (foo < 0) .. else if (foo > 0) ..` **does not match the case where `foo` is exactly 0.**

Other than that, there's no "security" benefit or anything. It's merely basic logic, and you need to implement the logic that you need for your use case.